# Incrementar campo sql al pulsar boton HTML mediante PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Estoy haciendo una web con PHP y HTML en la que los usuarios suben fotos con un titulo, una dirección, localidad y una descripción.

Ademas, existe un botón para votar dicha foto.

El problema lo estoy teniendo en dicho botón. No puedo conseguir que el campo SQL incremente en 1 al pulsar el botón.

Intente utilizando el método post como un formulario y que otro documento PHP maneje la consulta y actualice el valor en la tabla MySQL.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="relevanteBoton" method="post" action="rel.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Votar!">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
mysql_query("UPDATE 'fotos' SET 'relevancia=relevancia + 1' WHERE 'id = $id'");
```

Todavía no entiendo profundamente las consultas preparadas con PDO. Esto no me funcionó. No se si estaré haciendo cualquier cosa o tiene algo de concordancia. No se mucho PHP ni MySQL.

También intente utilizando AJAX y no obtuve buenos resultados.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
                function incrementar()
                {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "rel.php",
                    context: document.body
                    }).done(function() {
                    alert('incremented');
                    });
                    return false;
                }
-->
```

**HTML:**

```
<span id="button" onclick="javascript:return inc_counter();">Votar!</span>
```

¿Cómo podría resolverlo?

Comment: Te falta enviar el dato `id` porque lo recibes `$id = $_POST['id'];` pero no veo que lo estés enviando desde el formulario o desde AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas primero recuperar el contador en el que va la foto.
En tu PHP

```
$id = $_POST['id'];

function dameRelevancia($id)
{
$sql = "SELECT RELEVACIA FROM FOTOS WHERE ID = $id";//PREPARA SQL
$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);//EJECUTA LA SQL Y GUARDA
$cont = mysqli_fetch_array($result);//SACA LOS VALORES DE LO QUE REGRESO LA CONSULTA
return inval($cont["RELEVANCIA"]); //REGRESA TU VALOR PARSEANDOLO EN ENTERO
}


$voto = dameRelevancia($id) + 1;
mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE fotos SET relevancia = $voto WHERE 'id = $id'");
```

Te recomiendo uses mysqli o PDO ya que mysql no tiene soporte ya.

Saludos

Comment: Sólo tengo una duda, de dónde estas sacando el ID de la foto?